# Facing issue in importing packages from Parent directory ( Python 3 )

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-packaging

I have the following project structure: ( **Note:** This is a sample structure of my original project. )

```
proj1/
     __init__.py
    App/
        __init__.py
        Handlers/
                __init__.py
                Sum.py
    Tests/
         __init__.py
         Handlers/
                 __init__.py
                 SumHandler.py
    tests.py
```

My `tests.py` =>

```
import unittest
import Tests

def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    module = __import__('Tests.Handlers.SumHandler', fromlist=['object'])
    suite.addTest(unittest.TestSuite(map(unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule, [module])))
    return suite

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    test_suite = suite()
    result = runner.run (test_suite)
    print("---- START OF TEST RESULTS")
    print(result)
    print("---- END OF TEST RESULTS")
```

My `__init__.py` =>

```
import sys as _sys
class Package(object):
    def __init__(s, local):
        import os.path
        s.cache = {}
        s.local = dict((k, local[k]) for k in local)
        s.root = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(s.local["__file__"]))
    def __getattr__(s, k):
        if k in s.local: return s.local[k]
        if k in s.cache: return s.cache[k]
        path = list(s.local["_sys"].path)
        s.local["_sys"].path = [s.root]
        try:
            module = __import__(k, globals(), locals(), ['object'], 0)
            name = k[0].capitalize() + k[1:]
            s.cache[k] = getattr(module, name) if hasattr(module, name) else module
        finally: s.local["_sys"].path[:] = path
        return s.cache[k]
_sys.modules[__name__] = Package(locals())
```

My `SumHandler.py` =>

```
import unittest
import App

class SumHandler(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.a = 10
        self.b = 5
        self.sum = App.Handlers.Sum()

    def test_add(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.sum.add(self.a, self.b),15)

    def tearDown(self):
        del(self.a, self.b)
```

My `Sum.py` =>

```
class Sum():
    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y
```

I am using **unittest framework** to test the code from my App directory. Now when I run the `tests.py` file with the above directory structure I get the following error =>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Sharvin/proj_1/Tests/Handlers/SumHandler.py", line 9, in setUp
    self.sum = App.Handlers.Sum()
AttributeError: module 'App' has no attribute 'Handlers'
```

***Question:***

I am trying to import the whole `App` directory inside `SumHandler` package in `Tests/Handlers` so that I can import multiple packages from the `App` directory. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don’t use `if __name__=="__main__"` inside a package—running a file out of a package as a module doesn’t work well (if it works at all).

Comment: Is your question why your `Package.__getattr__` isn’t working?

Comment: No, it is a feature of Python packages that their contained modules are loaded separately, only when each is named by an `import`.

Comment: My question is as you can see the error when I use import App inside SumHandler.py I get the error can't import App. What am I doing wrong here? I don't know if I have done something wrong in `__getattr__` . Also How can I import parent directory so all the packages inside that directory get's imported. In this instance importing `App` directory will import all the packages inside that directory.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your last comment or share any resource or document regarding this? Thanks

Comment: If you have something this complex, you should probably try to package and install it, and test on that instead.

Comment: Okay so you mean I should make my `App/` directory as a package and then import it in the test directory?